# T4MVC urls in javascript: substitute route values

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, t4mvc

I do like using T4MVC and its strongly-typed URL's, and want to use them in JS, but have some problems. 
Let's say I want to load an url into a div:

```
$('#mydiv').load("@Url.Action(MVC.Home.Index())");  //that works
```

But what if my action is parameterized with some js-attribute value?

```
public ActionResult Index2(int id){}

var id = $('#mydiv').attr('index');
$('#mydiv').load("@Url.Action(MVC.Home.Index2(id))");  //this certainly doesn't work, since "id" is a JS variable
$('#mydiv').load("@Url.Action(MVC.Home.Index2(-1))".replace("-1", id));  //this is a workaround I use now, but don't like it :)
```

However, if my parameter is not an int but Guid, the workaround becomes ugly because guid-default value is too long..

What are the other solutions?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general approach might be ok. For the guid case, you can change:

```
@Url.Action(MVC.Home.Index2(-1))
```

to

```
@Url.Action(MVC.Home.Index2().AddRouteValue("id", -1))
```

This way you get around the type system and can pass whatever dummy value you want.

Comment: thanks, that's a good way, but if parameter names would change it simply will stop working..

Comment: Yes, you'll lose that small piece of T4MVC value. Not sure you can do better though. When fully using T4MVC (as in the first line), it will enforce the parameter type, and you're explicitly trying to use the wrong type :)